# What is barred circle icon in dock after install to new HD?

Tags: dock, repair

I just bought a SSD for my MacBook Pro and installed Lion on it and restored from a Time Machine backup. After a few updates and configuring a few things I am mostly good to go. However, Xcode and Aperture have a ghostly barred circle over their dock icons. I needed to download some components for Xcode to get it to run, but it seems fine, but the icon is wrong:

[image: The dock icon]

I assumed that it meant that there was a problem restoring the application, but I can't find any information on this. I guess I want to know what it means and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Does this persist after you launch each app that is affected?

Comment: I get a barred-circle icon anytime I drag a a new app onto an app-folder shortcut provided in the .dmg, or if I drag it directly into /Applications.  Logging out and logging in again fixes it.  I prevent it happening in the first place by dragging a new app onto my desktop first, where it will get its proper icon, and then into /Applications.  I've no idea why that happens or how it's related, but I'd bet the same solution would work in this case, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow, there was an error while restoring your backup.

Some user blamed [Norton Anti Virus](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100225150600825) (but I doubt you've installed this software), others [just re-installed the app](https://superuser.com/questions/116319/mac-os-x-applications-downloaded-from-internet-stuck-with-circle-with-diagonal). Both cases seems to work for some users, so you could try both :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that did it. When I first saw these icons I immediately looked up the apps in finder and saw that the barred circle was on those icons, too. But after reading the page at that link I simply threw the dock icons away after discovering that the barred icons were no longer on the original apps. I simply dragged them back to the dock. The real problem may be that when the apps have been updated the dock icons do not get refreshed.

Comment: Great! Glad to help you out!

Answer (score 2):

The icon is used in the Mac OS to identify applications that will no longer run due to OS-level changes.

- Classic Mac apps (pre-OS X) got the icon in OS X if they weren't Carbonized to run natively in OS X. You could use the Classic environment (essentially an OS 9 virtual machine) to run these apps until Leopard ended support for Classic.
- PowerPC apps got the icon in Lion as the Rosetta emulation system was no longer supported.
- The Dock will also use that icon to show apps that do not exist anymore and cannot be found. (If you put the apps back, the Dock won't remove the icon until it is relaunched.)

Comment: It may also be used for other problems as Xcode 4.3.3 was just released and I'm fairly certain it doesn't have those problems. But this is the first time I've seen it, so thanks for the hint about it being new in Lion.

Comment: Carbon apps didn't get disallowed in Lion, and the icon has been around quite a bit longer than just Lion.